# jquery Validation engine. Ajax error 200 parsererror

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

im trying to use the ajaxNameCallPhp to check if a username already exists in my database. I have never used this before so im struggling to get it working. When I input a username that already exists into my username field it just shows "Validating, please wait". Looking at firebug I can see an Ajax error: 200 parsererror being displayed.

Code snippet from members.php

```
userName: {
                    title: 'User Name',
                    list: false,
                    width: '15%',
                    inputClass: 'validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber],maxSize[20],ajax[ajaxNameCallPhp]]'
                },
                FirstName: {
                    title: 'First Name',
                    width: '20%',
                    inputClass: 'validate[required]'
                },
                LastName: {
                    title: 'Last Name',
                    width: '20%',
                    inputClass: 'validate[required]'
                },
                password: {
                    title: 'Password',
                    list: false,
                    type: 'password',
                    width: '20%',
                    inputClass: 'validate[required]'
                },
```

The validation on other fields works fine just the userName fails.

jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```
"ajaxNameCallPhp": {
                    "url":"ajaxValidateFieldName.php",
                    "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                },
```

my ajaxValidateFieldName.php:

```
<?php
include('dbConnect.php');

/* RECEIVE VALUE */
$validateValue=$_REQUEST['fieldValue'];
$validateId=$_REQUEST['fieldId'];


$validateError= "This username is already taken";
$validateSuccess= "This username is available";



    /* RETURN VALUE */
    $arrayToJs = array();
    $arrayToJs[0] = $validateId;


$sql_checkusername = "SELECT userName FROM tiptop_user WHERE userName = '$validateValue'";
$result=mysql_query($sql_checkusername );
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count=0){
$arrayToJs[1] = true; // RETURN true
echo json_encode($arrayToJs); // RETURN ARRAY username is available
} 

else {

for($x=0;$x<1000000;$x++){
if($x == 990000){
$arrayToJs[1] = false;
echo json_encode($arrayToJs);
}
}
}
?>
```

When I debug I can see that count = 1 and the following is returned: ["AndAda52",false]. Appologise I have never used this function before

Comment: parseerror means your json is invalid. show us the json.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, this is new to me which section is the json?

Comment: The response from the script you are requesting from.

Comment: @KevinB Having looked at the code on my virtual machine again I had an echo in to show the amount of rows being returned. Once I commented this out I no longer get the parsererror but still the username field just shows "validating, please wait" there are no errors displayed in firebug and all that shows in the Response window is: ["AndAda52",false] AndAda52 is the duplicate username I have entered

Comment: Where's your javascript?

Comment: @KevinB All the jquery files are in a script folder. The ValidationEngine.js files are in another folder in the script files and the ajaxValidateFieldName.php is in the same folder as my members.php. Your going to tell me that my files are in the wrong directories arnt you. Im going to cry if I have spent all day trying to work this out and its because they wernt located in the same folder.

Comment: No, that parts fine, i should have asked you to provide a sample of some relevant javascript in your question instead. I'm wondering if the response from your server-side script is in the format that the validation engine is expecting.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry for the late reply. Going off your comment I moved my ajaxValidateFieldName.php file to the same directory as the validationEngine scripts and although it didnt completely work I am making progress. When a username is entered the status changes to Username taken however it also says this when the username is available.. Also my include file for the dbConnect.php file how do I reference this back to the root folder? I didnt know so I had to create another copy of it in the same folder as the ajax file.

Comment: @KevinB finally sorted it! Once I had put them in the same folder (ajaxValidateFieldName and validationEngine scripts) all I needed to do was alter my ajax script slightly. I had: if($count=0) should be: if($count==0) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

ajaxValidateFieldName.php file needed to be in the same directory as the validateEngine script files. If statement in the ajax file needed changed from (if($count=0)) to (if($count==0))